# Tensorflow loss not changing and also computed gradients and applied batch norm but still loss is not changing?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, deep-learning, tensorflow

My Tensorflow loss is not changing. This is my code.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import math
import os
import nltk
import random
import tflearn
batch_size = 100
start = 0
end = batch_size
learning_rate = 0.01
num_classes = 8
path1 = "/home/indy/Downloads/aclImdb/train/pos"
path2 = "/home/indy/Downloads/aclImdb/train/neg"
path3 = "/home/indy/Downloads/aclImdb/test/pos"
path4 = "/home/indy/Downloads/aclImdb/test/neg"
time_steps = 300
embedding = 50
step = 1


def get_embedding():
    gfile_path = os.path.join("/home/indy/Downloads/glove.6B", "glove.6B.50d.txt")
    f = open(gfile_path,'r')
    embeddings = {}
    for line in f:
        sp_value = line.split()
        word = sp_value[0]
        embedding = [float(value) for value in sp_value[1:]]
        assert len(embedding) == 50
        embeddings[word] = embedding
    return embeddings

ebd = get_embedding()

def get_y(file_path):
    y_value = file_path.split('_')
    y_value = y_value[1].split('.')
    if y_value[0] == '1':
       return 0
    elif y_value[0] == '2':
         return 1
    elif y_value[0] == '3':
          return 2
    elif y_value[0] == '4':
          return 3
    elif y_value[0] == '7':
          return 4
    elif y_value[0] == '8':
          return 5
    elif y_value[0] == '9':
          return 6
    elif y_value[0] == '10':
          return 7 

def get_x(file_path):
    x_value = open(file_path,'r')
    for line in x_value:
        x_value = line.replace("<br /><br />","") 
        x_value = x_value.lower()
    x_value = nltk.word_tokenize(x_value.decode('utf-8'))
    padding = 300 - len(x_value)
    if padding > 0:
       p_value = ['pad' for i in range(padding)]
       x_value = np.concatenate((x_value,p_value))
    if padding < 0:
       x_value = x_value[:300]
    for i in x_value:
        if ebd.get(i) == None:
           ebd[i] = [float(np.random.normal(0.0,1.0)) for j in range(50)]
    x_value = [ebd[value] for value in x_value]
    assert len(x_value) == 300
    return x_value


def get_total_files(path1,path2,path3,path4):
    directory1 = os.listdir(path1)
    file_path1 = [os.path.join(path1,file) for file in directory1]
    directory2 = os.listdir(path2)
    file_path2 = [os.path.join(path2,file) for file in directory2]
    directory3 = os.listdir(path3)
    file_path3 = [os.path.join(path3,file) for file in directory3]
    directory4 = os.listdir(path4)
    file_path4 = [os.path.join(path4,file) for file in directory4]
    total_files_train = np.concatenate((file_path1,file_path2))
    total_files_test = np.concatenate((file_path3,file_path4))
    random.shuffle(total_files_train)
    random.shuffle(total_files_test)    
    x1 = [get_x(file) for file in total_files_train]
    y1 = [get_y(file) for file in total_files_train]
    x2 = [get_x(file) for file in total_files_test]
    y2 = [get_y(file) for file in total_files_test]
    return x1 , y1 , x2 , y2

total_files_train_x, total_files_train_y, total_files_test_x, total_files_test_y = get_total_files(path1,path2,path3,path4)


train_set_x = total_files_train_x[:10000]
validate_set_x = total_files_train_x[10000:15000]
test_set_x = total_files_test_x[0:5000]
train_set_y = total_files_train_y[:10000]
validate_set_y = total_files_train_y[10000:15000]
test_set_y = total_files_test_y[0:5000]


X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,time_steps,embedding])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])

def build_nlp_model(x, _units,num_classes,num_of_filters):
    x = tf.expand_dims(x,3)
    with tf.variable_scope("one"):      
         filter_shape = [1, embedding, 1, num_of_filters]
         conv_weights = tf.get_variable("conv_weights" , filter_shape, tf.float32, tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=0.0, stddev=1.0))
         conv_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_of_filters]))
         conv = tf.nn.conv2d(x, conv_weights, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding = "VALID")
         normalize = conv + conv_biases
         tf_normalize = tflearn.layers.normalization.batch_normalization(normalize)
         relu = tf.nn.elu(tf_normalize)
         pooling = tf.reduce_max(relu, reduction_indices = 3, keep_dims = True)
         outputs_fed_lstm = pooling

    with tf.variable_scope("two"):         
         filter_shape = [1, 1, 1, 1000]
         conv_weights = tf.get_variable("conv_weights" , filter_shape, tf.float32, tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=0.0, stddev=1.0))
         conv_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[1000]))
         conv = tf.nn.conv2d(outputs_fed_lstm, conv_weights, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding = "VALID")
         normalize = conv + conv_biases
         tf_normalize = tflearn.layers.normalization.batch_normalization(normalize)
         relu = tf.nn.elu(tf_normalize)
         pooling = tf.reduce_max(relu, reduction_indices = 3, keep_dims = True)
         outputs_fed_lstm = pooling

    with tf.variable_scope("three"):        
         filter_shape = [1, 1, 1, 1000]
         conv_weights = tf.get_variable("conv_weights" , filter_shape, tf.float32, tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=0.0, stddev=1.0))
         conv_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[1000]))
         conv = tf.nn.conv2d(outputs_fed_lstm, conv_weights, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding = "VALID")
         normalize = conv + conv_biases
         tf_normalize = tflearn.layers.normalization.batch_normalization(normalize)
         relu = tf.nn.elu(tf_normalize)
         pooling = tf.reduce_max(relu, reduction_indices = 3, keep_dims = True)
         outputs_fed_lstm = pooling

    with tf.variable_scope("four"):         
         filter_shape = [1, 1, 1, num_of_filters]
         conv_weights = tf.get_variable("conv_weights" , filter_shape, tf.float32, tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=0.0, stddev=1.0))
         conv_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_of_filters]))
         conv = tf.nn.conv2d(outputs_fed_lstm, conv_weights, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding = "VALID")
         normalize = conv + conv_biases
         tf_normalize = tflearn.layers.normalization.batch_normalization(normalize)
         relu = tf.nn.elu(tf_normalize)
         pooling = tf.reduce_max(relu, reduction_indices = 3, keep_dims = True)
         outputs_fed_lstm = pooling

    with tf.variable_scope("five"):         
         filter_shape = [1, 1, 1, num_of_filters]
         conv_weights = tf.get_variable("conv_weights" , filter_shape, tf.float32, tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=0.0, stddev=1.0))
         conv_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_of_filters]))
         conv = tf.nn.conv2d(outputs_fed_lstm, conv_weights, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding = "VALID")
         normalize = conv + conv_biases
         tf_normalize = tflearn.layers.normalization.batch_normalization(normalize)
         relu = tf.nn.elu(tf_normalize)
         pooling = tf.reduce_max(relu, reduction_indices = 3, keep_dims = True)
         outputs_fed_lstm = pooling

    x = tf.squeeze(outputs_fed_lstm, [2])     
    x = tf.transpose(x, [1, 0, 2])
    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 1])
    x = tf.split(0, time_steps, x)

    lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units = _units)

     # multi_lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([lstm] * lstm_layers, state_is_tuple = True)

    outputs , state = tf.nn.rnn(lstm,x, dtype = tf.float32)     

    weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([_units,num_classes]))
    biases  = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_classes]))

    logits = tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights) + biases
    return logits

logits = build_nlp_model(X,500,num_classes,1000)
c_loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits,Y)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(c_loss)


global_step = tf.Variable(0, name="global_step", trainable=False)
# decayed_learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(learning_rate,0,10000,0.9)
optimizer= tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
minimize_loss = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)   
with tf.variable_scope("four", reuse = True):
     weights = tf.get_variable("conv_weights") 
     grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss,[weights]) 
correct_predict = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, Y, 1)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_predict, tf.float32))


init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
     sess.run(init)
     for i in range(10):
         for j in range(100):
             x = train_set_x[start:end]
             y = train_set_y[start:end]
             start = end
             end += batch_size
             if start >= 10000:
                start = 0
                end = batch_size  
             sess.run(minimize_loss,feed_dict={X : x, Y : y})
             step += 1  
             gr_print = sess.run([grad for grad, _ in grads_and_vars], feed_dict={X : x, Y : y})
             print (gr_print)
         print ("One Epoch Finished")
         cost = sess.run(loss,feed_dict = {X: x,Y: y})
         accu = sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict = {X: x, Y: y})
         print ("Loss after one Epoch(Training) = " + "{:.6f}".format(cost) + ", Training Accuracy= " + "{:.5f}".format(accu))
         q = validate_set_x[:100]
         w = validate_set_y[:100]
         cost = sess.run(loss,feed_dict = {X: q,Y: w})
         accu = sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict = {X: q, Y: w})
```

My loss remains the same after many Epochs. So I think that I'm having vanishing gradient problem and so I applied batch normalization but I got no difference in results.I also tried overfitting the model, but I'm getting same results. I'm using `optimizer.compute_gradients` for computing gradients. Below are the results of gradients of loss with respect to different conv layers, and how they look like. Here is how my gradients look like with respect to first conv layers and with respect to 4th conv layer.

Code for gradients with respect to first conv layer:

```
with tf.variable_scope("one", reuse = True):
     weights = tf.get_variable("conv_weights") 
     grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss,[weights])


gr_print = sess.run([grad for grad, _ in grads_and_vars], feed_dict={X : x, Y : y})
           print (gr_print)
```

And this is what I get after one iteration:

```
[array([[[[  2.38197345e-06,  -1.04135906e-04,   2.60035231e-05, ...,
           -1.01550373e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   1.01060732e-06]],

        [[ -1.98007251e-06,   8.13827137e-05,  -8.14055747e-05, ...,
           -6.40711369e-05,   0.00000000e+00,   1.05516607e-04]],

        [[  4.51127789e-06,   2.21654373e-05,  -4.99439229e-05, ...,
            9.87191743e-05,   0.00000000e+00,   1.70595697e-04]],

        ..., 
        [[ -4.70160239e-06,  -8.67914496e-05,   2.50699850e-05, ...,
            1.18909593e-04,   0.00000000e+00,   2.43308150e-05]],

        [[ -1.18101923e-06,  -7.71943451e-05,  -3.41630148e-05, ...,
           -3.28040805e-05,   0.00000000e+00,  -6.01144784e-05]],

        [[ -1.98778321e-06,  -3.23160748e-05,  -5.44797731e-05, ...,
            2.23019324e-05,   0.00000000e+00,  -3.29296927e-05]]]], dtype=float32)]
```

Code for gradients with respect to 4th conv layer:

```
with tf.variable_scope("four", reuse = True):
     weights = tf.get_variable("conv_weights") 
     grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss,[weights])
gr_print = sess.run([grad for grad, _ in grads_and_vars], feed_dict={X : x, Y : y})
           print (gr_print)
```

And this what I get after one iteration:

```
[array([[[[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        , -6.21198082,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.                ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.              ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
           0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]]]], dtype=float32)]
```

After first layer, gradients with respect to 2nd,3rd,4th,5th conv layers all look like above. But there's one thing common among all the gradients with respect to conv layers which are after first conv layer, they all have one number in the entire gradient array,that is not zero as shown above in the output. And I also applied batch norm and I'm still getting the above results.

I'm totally confused, I don't know where the problem is?

And I've one more question, If I want to access variables like pooling, output_fed_lstm etc how can I access them?

```
with tf.variable_scope("one", reuse = True):
     weights = tf.get_variable("conv_weights") 
     grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss,[weights])
```

I know I can access variables like conv_weights 
as shown above.

```
with tf.variable_scope("one"):      
         filter_shape = [1, embedding, 1, num_of_filters]
         conv_weights = tf.get_variable("conv_weights" , filter_shape, tf.float32, tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=0.0, stddev=1.0))
         conv_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_of_filters]))
         conv = tf.nn.conv2d(x, conv_weights, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding = "VALID")
         normalize = conv + conv_biases
         tf_normalize = tflearn.layers.normalization.batch_normalization(normalize)
         relu = tf.nn.elu(tf_normalize)
         pooling = tf.reduce_max(relu, reduction_indices = 3, keep_dims = True)
         outputs_fed_lstm = pooling
```

But how can I access variables like pooling,outputs_fed_lstm etc which are also in scope "one" ?

Answer (score 0):

I jave just basic knowledge of tensorflow but I will try to guess the issue there.

Seems like the problem lies in the calls:

For conv2 to conv5:

conv = tf.nn.conv2d(outputs_fed_lstm, conv_weights, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding = "VALID")

You want to access outputs_fed_lstm declared within scope of conv4 so should be something like conv4.outputs_fed_lstm[map it to whatever the format in tensorflow is], instead you just seem to feedbacking the output_fed_lstm of the same convx to the input.

For conv1 the call is:
conv = tf.nn.conv2d(x, conv_weights, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding = "VALID")
Hence the gradients are valid and existing.